# JavaScript Navigating through a Class' array of objects to print each property

Tags: javascript, loops, class, properties

So I have a Worker class which extends a Person class in order to give it all of the properties you see below.

```js
class Worker extends Person {

    constructor(name, age, address, wage, position) {

        super(name, age, address);

        this.wage = 0;
        this.position = "";
    }
}
```

I also have a EmployeeList class which is basically an array of all Employees:

```js
class EmployeeList {

  //Initialize studentList array
  constructor(empList) {
    this.empList = [];
  }

  //Add studentObject to studentList
  addEmployee(employeeObject) {
    this.empList.push(employeeObject);
  }

  //delete studentObject from studentList
  deleteEmployee(employeeName) {
    let name = this.empList.findIndex((employeeName) => {
      return employeeName
    });
    this.empList.splice(name, 1);
  }
}
```

So the issue that I'm running into is I'm able to create an instance of EmployeeList

```js
let myEmployeeList = new EmployeeList();
```

and populate it with employees. However, I want to iterate through all of the properties of each Employee in myEmployeeList. I've tried a mixture of using Object.keys and Object.Values and Object.entries but haven't gotten anything to work. I would like the output to look like this when I console log:

```
name: George
age: 26
address: 18809 Oakridge Ct.
wage: 20
position: cook
name: Phil
age: 35
address: 4556 Royal Park Ave.
wage: 28
position: chef
name: Lizzy
age: 24
address: 1136 Rasberry Ct.
wage: 22
position: cook
```

Ultimately I want to be able to search by name or age or any of the properties so that's why I'm trying to figure out how to loop through everything.

**I have seen similar posts but I haven't found any that have helped me with my specific issue. If one already exists then I apologize for the dupe**

Comment: add a method to `EmployeeList` to get employee list and iterate that list

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not super familiar with JS though. How would I write a getter for empList?

Comment: `getEmployeeList() {
   return this.empList;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

There are two things in your post:

1. Display your `Worker`

Why you're not just adding a display method to your class `Worker` or `Person`. And iterate and call the display method of your worker in your employeeList by iterating through it.

2. Find the value of a property with your EmployeeList

Just add a method in `EmployeeList` to find if any of your employee properties contain your search. something like this :

```js
searchEmployee(search) {
    return empList.filter(employee => {
        return Object.values(employee).includes(search);
    })
}
```

You'll get a new list of any employees who have property containing your search.